# How do you access exported functions from within each other?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a constructor and a function like

```
function Node(args) {}

function tree(args) 
{
    new Node(args)
}
```

Now i need to use the `tree()` function in an another file so i guess

```
module.exports = {
    Node: Node,
    tree: tree,
}
```

is the right way to do it. But when i use this using

```
var tools = require('./file')
```

Now, when i use the tree function, how will the call to `Node()` from `tools.tree()` be handled (I'm guessing this wont work) ? Is there a proper way to do this ?

Comment: firstly, did you try it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just use their names, they're in-scope for each other and the other things within your module. They're just not *global*. Your `new Node(args)` in `tree` is just fine.

What matters isn't where you're calling `tree` from, it's where you're calling `Node` from — which is code in `tree`, which has access to `Node`.